# how can i display new images at the top of the table view

Tags: iphone

i am getting images from the .net web server by passing xml parameters.

i am getting more that 20 images and i am saving images in iphone simulator documents one by one like this.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
        if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"photo"])
        {
            recordResults_photo = FALSE;
            NSData *decode = [Base64 decode:resultData_photo];
            NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decode encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSData *decodedimage = [Base64 decode:theXML];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:decodedimage];
                NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                NSLog(@"saving msg image %d",i);
                NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image%d.png",docDir,i];
                NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
                [data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];

    }
}
```

then images are saving like this image0.png,image1.png,image2.png.....

and i am displaying these images in table view like this.

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image%d.png",docDir,indexPath.row];

        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 05, 30, 30)];
        img.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
```

then images are displayed well.

But now i have a problem here.

I am getting some more new images from the web server and i need to display them at the top of the table view.

As per my implementation i need to change all the image names.

That's not the proper way,is there any alternate way or better way than me.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

[how to add new elements in array at the top of the table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758192/how-to-add-new-elements-in-array-at-the-top-of-the-table-view/5758289#5758289)

It's much better than my answer to the same question but both would work.

I just confirmed that this does shift the objects down by one, so this should work.

EDIT: I'm sorry, I misread your question. As for changing the image names, the only way I see thats possible is by iterating through the array and changing the names once new objects are added.

Comment: but how can i images to array.

Comment: Are you unable to add UIImage's to an NSMutableArray?