# Array with multiple values per index?

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm learning swift, and I do the sololearn course to get some knowledge, but I bumped into something that I don't understand.
It is about modifying an array's values. The questionable part states the following:

> In the following example, the elements with index 1, 2, 3 are replaced with two new values.

```
shoppingList[1...3] = [“Bananas”, “Oranges”]
```

How can an one dimensional array take more than one value per index? And how do I access them? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Use Tuple for each index. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25838682/14733292

Comment: What the code above does is the same as `replaceSubrange` method where you replace any number of elements with another collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this code does is replacing the element of `shoppingList` in the `1...3` range using [`Array.subscript(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2944258-subscript)

That means considering this array:

```
var shoppingList = ["Apples", "Strawberries", "Pears", "Pineaples"]
```

that with:

```
shoppingList[1...3] = ["Bananas", "Oranges"]
```

`Strawberries`, `Pears` and `Pineaples` will be replaced by `Bananas` and `Oranges`.

so the resulting array will be: `Apples`, `Bananas`, `Oranges`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I didn't understand! For some reason I thought that in the range from 1 to 3 every element would change to "bananas" and "oranges", so the array would have two values per index, and that got me confused. It is clear now!

Answer (score 3):

When you assign to a range of indices in an array (`array[1...3]`), those elements are removed from the array and the new elements are 'slotted in' in their place. This can result in the array growing or shrinking.

```
var array = Array(0...5)
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array[1...3] = [-1, -2]
// [0, -1, -2, 3, 4]
```

Notice how our array's length is now one element shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tuple (Value, Value), or create a `struct` to handle your values there, in fact if you plan to reuse this pair or value, a `struct` is the way to go.

By the way, there's no need to add `[1..3]`, just put the values inside the brackets.

```
struct Value {
    var name: String
    var lastName: String
}

let values = [Value(name: "Mary", lastName: "Queen"), Value(name: "John", lastName: "Black")]

// Access to properties
let lastName = values[1].lastName

// OR

let tuples = [("Mary", "Queen"), ("John", "Black")]

let lastNameTuple = tuples[1].1
```

Hope you're enjoying Swift!

Comment: Thanks for your examples! But I'm still curious if the example given by SoloLearn makes any sense just by itself?

Comment: No need for any tuples, the code in the question works fine as it is.