# Swift Array join EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: arrays, join, swift

Array `–join(_:)` function throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
var ar1 = [1,2,3]
var ar2 = [5,6,7]
var res = ar1.join(ar2)
```

Has anyone faced this problem? Any solution or suggestion?

[image]

Comment: join is not the operation to add , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array

Comment: so what's thy porpoise of this method? It takes Sequence and return and Array [T].

Comment: The join method for strings in objective is perhaps better named: `componentsJoinedByString` but is not available for arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is

```
var ar1 = [1,2,3]
var ar2 = [5,6,7]
var res = ar1 + ar2
```

You would usually use join() to flatten a two level array by inserting the elements from another array in between first level elements:

```
var ar1 = [1,2,3]
var ar2 = [[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
let res = ar1.join(ar2) // [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12]
```

The function works in the same fashion for strings also:

```
let ar1 = ["1","2","3"]
let res = ".!?".join(ar1) // "1.!?2.!?3"
```

Comment: Note that your last example calls the join method of the String class, not of the Array class as in the question.

Comment: in the method declaration - 
func join<S : Sequence where [T] == [T]>(elements: S) -> [T]
if method is suppose to take an arrays of arrays it should be sometinh like this 
`<S : Sequence where S.Element == [[T]]`

Comment: @KonstantinKoval: As I understand it `[[T]]` is treated as `Sequence<[T]>`.