# Purpose of Array "Join" function in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, high-order-component

What is the use of `join()` in arrays?

In other languages, it is used to join elements of array into string. For example,
[Ruby Array.join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join)

I've asked some question about join() in 
[Swift Array join EXC_BAD_ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24820446/swift-array-join-exc-bad-access)

Comment: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24820941/1187415 to your previous question gives two concrete applications of join() ...

Comment: how about addapt the code from them? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21313276/4920678

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Here is a somewhat useful example with strings:

Swift 3.0

```
let joiner = ":"
let elements = ["one", "two", "three"]
let joinedStrings = elements.joined(separator: joiner)
print("joinedStrings: \(joinedStrings)")
```

output:

> joinedStrings: one:two:three

Swift 2.0

```
var joiner = ":"
var elements = ["one", "two", "three"]
var joinedStrings = elements.joinWithSeparator(joiner)
print("joinedStrings: \(joinedStrings)")
```

output:

> joinedStrings: one:two:three

Swift 1.2:

```
var joiner = ":"
var elements = ["one", "two", "three"]
var joinedStrings = joiner.join(elements)
println("joinedStrings: \(joinedStrings)")
```

The same thing in Obj-C for comparison:

```
NSString *joiner = @":";
NSArray *elements = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"];
NSString *joinedStrings = [elements componentsJoinedByString:joiner];
NSLog(@"joinedStrings: %@", joinedStrings);
```

output:

> joinedStrings: one:two:three

Comment: This isn't exactly answering the question. The OP asked for the join method on an array.  You mentioned the join method on a string, which takes an array.

The confusing part is that a normal array join methods take a string as an argument and join the array with the string, however, the array join method in string takes in an array, and joins each element of itself with the array given as an argument.

Comment: There is some context missing: This join function was changed after the initial release, the question/answer addresses that change of functionality.

Comment: As a sidenote: `joinWithSeparator` does work for Arrays with Strings, id est `[String]`, but not other Array types like `[Int]`

Answer (score 0):

Following up on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825906/purpose-of-array-join-function-in-swift#comment54140263_24826511), to join an array of integers in Swift 4:

```swift
print([4, 5, 6].map(String.init).joined(separator: "->")) // => 4->5->6
```