# How to save data to an array?

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift

I have a `[String]` called `tableData`. I want to save data to that array whenever I get new data from another view controller.
How can I do that?

```
var NewPlaylistName: String?
var NewImageCover: String?

var tableData = ["Evo X", "458", "GTR", "Evo X", "458", "GTR", "Evo X", "458", "GTR", "Evo X", "458", "GTR"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if NewPlaylistName != nil {
        tableData += ["\(NewPlaylistName!)"]
        tableImages += ["evox.jpg"]

        var newTableData = tableData
        println(newTableData)
    }
}
```

If I run the code above I always get:

```
[Evo X, 458, GTR, Evo X, 458, GTR, Evo X, 458, GTR, Evo X, 458, GTR, sDfsad]
```

...the same total of array even though I already renew the data.
What I want to know is, how can I add more data to the array?

For example:

```
[Evo X, 458, GTR, Evo X, 458, GTR, Evo X, 458, GTR, Evo X, 458, GTR, sDfsad, afasds]
```

...and then add more when there is new data:

```
[Evo X, 458, GTR, Evo X, 458, GTR, Evo X, 458, GTR, Evo X, 458, GTR, sDfsad, afasds, kljkl]
```

...and so on.

Comment: Instead you do it - tableData.append(NewPlaylistName!)

Comment: something [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array) my help

Comment: @Amit89 I've tried that, the result is the same.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni yes , I have a value on NewPlaylistName.

Comment: @EgaSetyaPutra, You want to add NewPlaylistName value to tableData array right. ?

Answer (score 1):

To add an element to the end of the array, use the `.append()` method or the `+= operator`. These two statements do the same:

```
myArray.append(23)
myArray += 29
```

The array [1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17] appends two numbers, changing to:  [1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,23,29]
The advantage to the += operator is you can append another array if the elements are of the same type in both arrays.

```
myArray += [31, 37]
```

results in [1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,23,29,31,37] In Swift, operators keep a consistency across type, which might make some traditional programmers a bit squeamish. The `+=` in their mind is an `arithmetic operator`. You should not use it for arrays, only for incrementing numbers, like we did in the for loop. Swift continues such consistency with merging two arrays with the + operator

```
var myStringArray = ["apple","pear","banana","raspberry"]
var myOtherStringArray = ["Pepperoni","Sausage"]
var jointArray = myStringArray + myOtherStringArray
```

This code results in jointArray being ["apple","pear","banana","raspberry","Pepperoni","Sausage"]

To insert an element at a particular position, use the `.insert(at:index)` method, remembering that the first index is zero:

```
myArray.insert(2,atindex:2)
```

This results in [1,2,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,23,29,31,37]

To change an element, assign a value to the specific element, like this:

```
var myArray = ["apple","pear","banana","raspberry"]
myArray[1] = "blackberry"
```

Will change myArray to ["apple","blackberry","banana","raspberry"]. You can change a range of values if both arrays are the same type.

```
var myArray = ["apple","pear","banana","raspberry"]
myArray[1...2] = ["beagle bone","arduino"]
```

Will change  ["apple","blackberry","banana","raspberry"] to ["apple","beagle bone","arduino","raspberry"] . Range values specify the range to replace. You can replace with fewer items

```
myArray[1..3] = ["blackBerry", "kit kat"]
```

Changes elements 1,2,3 to only two elements making the array ["apple","beagle bone","arduino","raspberry"] to ["apple","blackBerry", "kit kat"]

Reference from : [array-in-swift](http://makeapppie.com/2014/08/13/swift-tutorial-how-to-use-an-array-in-swift/)

This might helps you :)

Comment: Holy cow! hahaha.. Lols.. a lot of effort.. I thank you for this sir.. :) :)

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the reference.Just follow that

```
  STEP 1:If you want to  append more elements  to your array, you can  use the += operator, or the extend function.

   tableData += ["\(NewPlaylistName!)"]
   tableData.extend(["\(NewPlaylistName!)"])
```

If you want to need some detail explanation,just follow the below reference.You will get answer.

[Add an element to an array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array[1])

Comment: I already did that tough, What I need is the array keep added if there is new data not renew the last data on array

Answer (score -1):

You can define any array Like this.

```
var myArr= [];
```

then you can add whatever data (any DataType or Object) you want to this array at any point of execution like this

```
myArr.push(anyDataEntry);
```

or you can access the array like this

```
for (i in myArr) 
{
    //myArr[i]
}
```

Comment: xcode says "NSArray doesn't have member called push"

Comment: instead of push use **.append() **

Comment: Sorry, I assumed its plane JavaScript.