# Append arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a question, is it possible to append an array of string in an other array. (in Swift)

```
var array: [String] = []
var array2: [String] = []

array.append("test")
print(array)
example: ["test", "test", "test", "test"]
```

How can I append just the string "test", "test", "test", "test" in array2 in ()?

```
print(array2)
example: [("test", "test", "test", "test")]
```

In the end I would like to have this as result:

```
print(array2)

[("test", "test", "test", "test"),("test", "test", "test", "test"), ("test", "test", "test", "test")]
```

Comment: @shadowof you should add answers, if you're going to write the answer anyway :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an element to an array in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: @SpacyRicochet question too stupid to perform more than 15 symbols and make answer; also its probably duplicate or even illegal (syntax)

Comment: The information you need is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
let array: [String] = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
var array2: [String] = ["test4", "test5", "test6"]

array2.appendContentsOf(array)

print(array2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`appendContentsOf(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structm/Array/s:FSa16appendContentsOfuRd__s14CollectionTypexzWd__9Generator7Element_rFqd__T_), you can use the `+=` operator to append to an existing array:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = [4, 5, 6]

a += b

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be as follows:

```
let array1   = ["Something"]
let array2   = ["Else"]
let combined = array1 + array2
print(combined) // ["Something", "Else"]
```

or

```
let array1 = ["Something"]
var array2 = ["Else"]
array2 = array1 + array2
print(array2) //["Something", "Else"]
```