# Insert element into [(String, String)] tuple in swift

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I'm using a WKInterfacePicker and there is a need of inserting dynamic data into the array of the format [(String, String)]. I can insert data statically into this array like,

```
var cc:[(String, String)] = [
("Item 1", "Row 1"),
("Item 2", "Row 2")]
```

Can anyone please help me how to insert data into this dynamically ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an element to an array in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: It's array of (String,String). I am unable to append a string to array and then appending an array to it...

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 this is an array of tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myArray = [(String, String)]()

for index in 1...20 {
    myArray.append(("Item \(index)", "Row \(index)"))
}

print(myArray) // "[("Item 1", "Row 1"), ("Item 2", "Row 2"), ("Item 3", "Row 3"), ("Item 4", "Row 4"), ("Item 5", "Row 5"), ("Item 6", "Row 6"), ("Item 7", "Row 7"), ("Item 8", "Row 8"), ("Item 9", "Row 9"), ("Item 10", "Row 10"), ("Item 11", "Row 11"), ("Item 12", "Row 12"), ("Item 13", "Row 13"), ("Item 14", "Row 14"), ("Item 15", "Row 15"), ("Item 16", "Row 16"), ("Item 17", "Row 17"), ("Item 18", "Row 18"), ("Item 19", "Row 19"), ("Item 20", "Row 20")]\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how can I provide that tuple1 values dynamically ?

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: The data which I am expecting is a for loop integer 1 to 20 converted into string

Comment: @PradheepNarendranP is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for an insertion of data into the tuple with the format of [(String, String)]()

Comment: @PradheepNarendranP if you find my answer helpful, please mark it as the correct answer, thanks.

Comment: I am looking for a tuple insertion as you mentioned in your answer. I got it working!