# swift 3 update syntax from swift 2

Tags: swift, syntax, inout

in swift 2.2 its work:

```
var messages = [JSQMessage]()

//...
for i in 1...10 {
 let sender = (i%2 == 0) ? "Server" : self.senderId
 let messageContent = "Message nr. \(i)"
 var message = JSQMessage(senderId: sender, displayName: sender, text: messageContent)
 self.messages += [message] //Cannot convert value of type '[JSQMessage]' to expected argument type 'inout_'
}
```

in swift 3 give me error. tried to use

```
self.messages += [&message] // Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

how to fix?

Comment: How is `self.messages` defined?

Comment: var messages = [JSQMessage]()

Comment: @JAL:   That thread shows alternative solutions, but I don't see why `messages += [message]` should not compile.

Comment: Compiles fine for me – perhaps try cleaning your build folder? Usually you get that kind of error when `message` is optional, although that doesn't appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`self.messages.append(message)`

There are a lot of variants of appending:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24002784/1979882

Comment: Instead of linking to another post on Stack Overflow in an answer, flag or vote to close questions as duplicates.