# Swift - insert new array at the beginning of another array

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I want to insert an array at the beginning of another array. How can I do that in Swift?

Basically, when the user scrolls to top, I get the data from the server and want to present the new data at the top, not at the bottom.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 { // user reached the top
        if (self.loadMore == true) {
            self.page += 1
            self.getUserData(Page:self.page)
        } 
    }
}

func getUserData(Page:Int) {
    DataService().getData(page:Page) { data, error, errorDic in
        if error != nil {
            //oops
            return
        }

        if (self.loadMore == true) {
          self.data += data!
        } 

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369247/4415445