# How to append an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

This is my array

```
 var docData: [String: Any] = [
             "timestamp":Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000),
             "photo": photo_uri,
             "name": name.text ?? "
             ]
```

I would like to add the next item into the array ["email": email.text ?? ""]

The following does not work

```
docData += ["email": email.text ?? ""]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't create an array... you created a dictionary. In which case you would set the key to the value. A dictionary is a collection of key and value pairs.

```
docData["email"] = email.text ?? ""
```