# how to insert the data in the array of object

Tags: ios

how to add object in array.

I have :- var `datasourceModel:QM_ChartDataSourceModel`

in datasourceModel i have output as:-

```
<QM.QM_OfferModel: 0x7aecea50>
<QM.QM_OfferModel: 0x7aecfb30>
<QM.QM_OfferModel: 0x7aed0e40>
<QM.QM_OfferModel: 0x7aed0ec0>
<QM.QM_OfferModel: 0x7aed0f70>
```

in here:-

```
var insertedArray:QM_CartModel?
```

in this my output as :`<QM.QM_CartModel: 0x7ae4a020>`

So i need to add insertedArray in the datasourceModel

How to add?

my cartmodel:-

```
  //models.........
    var offerdetailModel:QM_OfferModel?

    init(withoffermodel  newofferdetailtModel:QM_OfferModel){
        offerdetailModel = newofferdetailtModel
        print(offerdetailModel?.name)
        offerdetailAddName = offerdetailModel?.name
        offerdetailid = offerdetailModel?.id

    }
```

the values are there in offerdetailModel

so i need to insert the offerdetailmodel?.name from the

.how to insert this value

Comment: `insertedArray.append(your_element)` <-- Have you tried this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add an element to an array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002733/add-an-element-to-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: @dahiya_boy i have updated my code.So how to add according,please check

Comment: try this  let obj   :  DictModel   =  QM_OfferModel Model() obj.TotalComments                   =       0 obj.engagement_comment_id           =       0
            obj.comment                         =       (commentTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))!
            obj.comment_user_name               =       userDefaultObj.userName!.capitalized
            obj.comment_user_id                 =       0
            obj.comment_user_image              =       ""

            self.feedCommentDictArray.append(obj)